# Deviating from instructions, fun yet informative Structure exercise

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I am studying for a final, and fear I am spending too much time on this topic, so I wanted some input. This will be kind of a long read, so I hope someone sees this. The following question is in the book, "Beginning C, from novice to professional" :

"Define a struct type with the name Length that represents a length in yards, feet,
and inches. Define an add() function that will add two Length arguments and return
the sum as type Length. Define a second function, show(), that will display the value
of its Length argument. Write a program that will use the Length type and the add()
and show() functions to sum an arbitrary number of lengths in yards, feet, and inches
that are entered from the keyboard and output the total length."

Which I interpreted like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"

struct length
{
    float FT;
    float YD;
    float IN;

};

struct length ReadIT(char sym[])
{
    struct length Convert;
    float dummy;
    printf("Enter %s\n",sym);
    scanf("%f",&dummy);
    Convert.FT = dummy;
    Convert.YD = dummy/3;
    Convert.IN = dummy*12;
    return(Convert);
};
struct length Add(struct length first, struct length second)
{
    struct length total;
    total.FT = first.FT+second.FT;
    total.YD = first.YD + second.YD;
    total.IN = first.IN + second.IN;
    return total;
};
void Show(struct length Convert )
{
    printf("Conversions FT: %.2f\n",Convert.FT );
    printf("Conversions YD: %.2f\n",Convert.YD );
    printf("Conversions IN: %.2f\n",Convert.IN );
}
void ShowSum(struct length total)
{
    printf("total FT: %.2f\n",total.FT );
    printf("total YD: %.2f\n",total.YD );
    printf("total IN: %.2f\n",total.IN );
}


int main(void)
{

char cmd = 'n';
struct length L1,L2;
do
{

    L1 = ReadIT("Length 1");
    Show(L1);
    L2 = ReadIT("Length 2");
    Show(L2);
    Add(L1,L2);
    ShowSum(Add(L1,L2));//adds up the two lengths , but how do I store them?
    printf("Would you like to add more lengths? Type 'y' to continue");            

    scanf("%s",&cmd);
    }
    while(tolower(cmd)=='y');
    printf("The total of all lengths is : ");

    return 0;
}
```

Also, since this came out of the book: I found out that I was supposed to interpret it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define INCHES_PER_FOOT 12
#define FEET_PER_YARD    3

struct Length
{
  unsigned int yards;
  unsigned int feet;
  unsigned int inches;
};

struct Length add(struct Length first, struct Length second);
void show(struct Length length);

int main(void)
{
  char answer = 'n';
  struct Length length;
  struct Length total = { 0,0,0};
  int i = 0;
  do
  {
    printf("Enter a length in yards, feet, and inches: ");
    scanf(" %d %d %d", &length.yards, &length.feet, &length.inches);
    total = add(total,length);
    printf("Do you want to enter another(y or n)?: ");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    fflush(stdin);
   }while(tolower(answer) == 'y');
  printf("The total of all the lengths is: ");
  show(total);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

struct Length add(struct Length first, struct Length second)
{
  unsigned long inches = 0;
  struct Length sum;
  inches = first.inches + second.inches+
    INCHES_PER_FOOT*(first.feet+second.feet+FEET_PER_YARD* (first.yards+second.yards));
  sum.inches = inches%INCHES_PER_FOOT;
  sum.feet = inches/INCHES_PER_FOOT;
  sum.yards = sum.feet/FEET_PER_YARD;
  sum.feet %= FEET_PER_YARD;
  return sum;
}

void show(struct Length length)
{
  printf("%d yards %d feet %d inches", length.yards,length.feet,length.inches);     
}
```

When I saw this answer, my first thought was, "I could have done that", but it made it sound like they wanted all this addition of the lengths done separately every two entered, and the total of individual FT, YD, &IN done independently.  Now I'm obsessed with finishing my version,but I've hit a wall. Can some one get me going?

Comment: What wall have you hit? Personally, I'd convert the whole lot down to the lowest unit (inches), do the math and then convert the results back into yards and feet for the display. It means you can't have, for example, 3 yards 17 feet and 24 inches but I'd consider that a bonus!

Comment: The wall I hit was I can't think of a way to store the total from the first loop around and then add it to the total from the next loop around, take THAT total store it as one variable , then repeat this over and over as long as the user wants.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&cmd);` --> `scanf(" %c", &cmd);`

Comment: You can either pass a pointer to a return structure to store the result of add or, by converting it into inches, return and save the result as an integer.

Comment: I want to say I thought of that, but wouldn't the pointer I pass overwrite the value every once through the loop, and the return structure only accept one argument? I feel like understanding this would be a level up for me.

Answer (score 0):

> The wall I hit was I can't think of a way to store the total from the
>   first loop around and then add it to the total from the next loop
>   around, take THAT total store it as one variable , then repeat this
>   over and over as long as the user wants.

You can do it quite similar to how it's done in the book's solution:

```
  struct Length total = { 0, 0, 0 }, subtotal;
…
    ShowSum(subtotal = Add(L1, L2)); // adds up the two lengths and stores the sum
    total = add(total, subtotal);
```